# Rotating a model in GLM

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glm-math

hey ive been working with [GLM](http://www.3dcodingtutorial.com/Working-with-3D-models/Getting-GLM.html) and i have been noticing that im not able to find a function to rotate the model.

There isnt much to this question, but im wondering if theres a way to rotate a GLM model, or rotate and single model in my opengl program.

if so then can you give some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't explicitly rotate models, you apply a rotation to the modelview matrix. Read up on how the OpenGL matrix stack works, and on how to use glMatrixMode and glRotate [here](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version2.1/glspec21.pdf).

It is the same in later versions of OpenGL, except in those, you implement the matrix stuff yourself and do the transform in a shader rather than using built-in functionality.

Comment: woo thanks, i looked at the book a bit, and found some examples, now i get it. thanks alot :D